# Python: encapsulating a string

Tags: python, oop, encapsulation

I wanted to create a string-like object that would define some extra methods that the basic `str` type doesn't have. Subclassing the `str` type is apparently not the way to go, so I thought about using the encapsulation strategy but can't figure out how to make the object act like a string when passed to other functions such as `open`.

```
class StringLike(object):

    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string

    def __str__(self, string):
        return self.string

s = StringLike('~/Desktop/test.txt')
with open(s, 'w') as handle: handle.write('Hello world')

#----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, StringLike found
```

Comment: Why does subclassing str not working for you? I don't see any reason for that.

Comment: From your use case, it looks like you actually want to subclass `file` and extend it with string-like behavior, as opposed to subclassing `str`.

Comment: You can for sure subclass `str`: just remember that being an immutable object if you are interested in customizing instance creation (something like converting to upper case, etc. etc.) then you have to override `__new__` http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization , otherwise just go as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do either

```
with open(s.string, 'w') as handle: handle.write('Hello world')
```

or

```
with open(str(s), 'w') as handle: handle.write('Hello world')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite it's `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods, like this:

This will act as a normal string, except it has the extra method from_str, you can add many more extra methods as you please.

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # define your internal stuff here, with self.__dict__
        self.__dict__['name'] = name

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.name.__getattribute__(attr)

    def from_str(self, txt):
        self.name = txt

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if not attr in self.__dict__:
         return self.name.__setattr__(attr, value)
        else:
          self.__dict__[attr] = value


student = Student('test')
print student.upper()
>>>TEST
student.from_str('foo')
>>> print student.upper()
FOO
```